# PyMongo create unique index with 2 or more fields

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

How can i create index in pymongo with 2 fields, to be unique together?

I have this code:

```
self.db[self.mongo_collection].create_index("url", unique=True)
```

but i need to be unique with `url` and `category`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to create a compound index and set `unique` to `True` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-indexes):

> If you use the unique constraint on a compound index, then MongoDB will enforce uniqueness on the combination of values rather than the individual value for any or all values of the key.

```
self.db[self.mongo_collection].create_index(
    [("url", pymongo.DESCENDING), ("category", pymongo.ASCENDING)],
    unique=True
)
```

Comment: here is the link to [create_index](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index) specification.

Comment: The link to create_index has moved: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index